# Newbie Jquery questions - versions and linking to source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 questions regarding these jquery references that are throughout a website I"m working with.  I'm more comfortable with php, css, html and mysql, but not so much with javascript and jquery.

With that being said.....

Let's say I have the jquery file located here:  `mysite.com/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js`

Question 1: That jquery file has been called it the `src` reference 3 different ways on different pages. Is one of those methods better/faster/more efficient than the others?

```
1.  src = "http://www.mysite/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"

2.  src = "js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"

3.  src = "/home/hostingaccountname/public_html/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"
```

Question 2:  Some pages refer to `/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and others (presumable made later) refer to `/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js`.  Is it safe to assume that 1.8.3 is an uppgrade to 1.3.2 and that I could replace all the 1.3.2 reference with 1.8.3?  Does it work this way or am I making a bad/dangerous assumption?

Sorry, I know these are probably dumb questions, but I want to be safe before I start gloablly changing the many different references to jquery throughout this site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer1:** You need to give relative path for your jquery file location. Let say that you have several website that uses same code structure. If you give jquery location like 1, your jquery will not be able to found on some of your domains. There is no need to say something about 3, because you are giving your system path information to frontend user. Do not use option 3. Also, I suggest you to load jquery from cdn like,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Answer2:** If you update jquery version, some of your code may give error or warning. First test your upgrade on your local and after successful operation upgrade your jquery version. If you have errors, fix them and upgrade jquery. Also, if you have unit tests for your js, this will help you on upgrading jquery. Upgrade jquery and run your tests, and see if where are the errors

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  So for question 2, basically it comes down to testing before converting.  For question 1 - thanks for your clear answer on the src....however, are you saying it's better to not even have this stuff on my site and just link to it elsewhere?  There is a lot of traffic on this webiste - would you still recommend the CDN?

Comment: Yes. If you have unit tests already, it will help you for upgrading

Comment: if you use CDN like googleapis, traffic will ne redirected to google and cannot use your traffic. Also, CDN uptime percentage almost 100%. Use CDN

Answer (score 0):

To question 1:
src = "http://www.mysite/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" is ok. But if u change domain name u have to refactor it.

src = "js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" should be --> src = "/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" - this one should be used.

src = "/home/hostingaccountname/public_html/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" will not work.

To question 2:
New version has more functions but some is deprecated from the older one. That means some scripts may not work. Better use latest version except u have some old scripts. Then u can use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js. Already there's 1.11 and 2.x

You can use jquery hosted in CDN. 
E.g. //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

More info http://jquery.com/download/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1.

I would prefer solution 2: most common and not neccessarily faster (non of them as far as I remind).
However, you can set your javascript immport just before the ending `</body>` tag. This way, if your javascript are heavy to load, the page will be displayed before the end of loading. Otherwise, you have to wait the end of loading, and then the page is load. The first idea is more user-friendly.

Question 2.
Yes, it is a good practice to set the version in the name of the plug-in javascript librairy you are using. You have this way a better tracking of what you are using in your project.
So, you have to change the name and the content to upgrade, as you would have understand.